# JAXB and property ordering

Tags: java, jaxb, xml-binding

I want the serialized XML output from my Java class to honor the ordering of the properties in the Java class.

It seems that JAXB orders alphabetically.

I can override this by using `@XmlType` with *propOrder* and specifying ALL of the properties, but I have a class with many properties and these are not yet finalized.

I read that specifying an empty *propOrder* would do it but it don't.

My example class:

```
package test;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement
//@XmlType(propOrder={"company", "scheme", "agreementNumber"})
@XmlType(propOrder={}) // makes no difference - still alphabetical in XML 
public class CustomerPlan2 {

    private String company;
    private String scheme;
    private String agreementNumber;

    @XmlElement(name="Company")
    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }
    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="Scheme")
    public String getScheme() {
        return scheme;
    }
    public void setScheme(String scheme) {
        this.scheme = scheme;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="AgreementNumber")
    public String getAgreementNumber() {
        return agreementNumber;
    }
    public void setAgreementNumber(String agreementNumber) {
        this.agreementNumber = agreementNumber;
    }
}
```

My serialize code:

```
    CustomerPlan2 cp2 = new CustomerPlan2();

    cp2.setCompany("company");
    cp2.setScheme("scheme");
    cp2.setAgreementNumber("agreementnumber");
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(CustomerPlan2.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();

    marshaller.marshal(cp2, new FileWriter("C:\\temp\\out.xml"));
```

Output:

```
    <customerPlan2>
      <AgreementNumber>agreementnumber</AgreementNumber> 
      <Company>company</Company> 
      <Scheme>scheme</Scheme> 
    </customerPlan2>
```

I want my output to be (as the property order of my class):

```
    <customerPlan2>
      <Company>company</Company>
      <Scheme>scheme</Scheme> 
      <AgreementNumber>agreementnumber</AgreementNumber> 
    </customerPlan2>
```

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 80):

It's possible using:

```
@XmlType (propOrder={"prop1","prop2",..."propN"})
```

Just uncomment the code like this:

```
//@XmlType(propOrder={"company", "scheme", "agreementNumber"})
```

This is the correct usage.

Comment: True: http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_6_2_2-Annotation-for-Classes-XmlType.html#Annotation%20for%20Classes:%20XmlType

Answer (score 30):

Note:  I lead [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/#moxy)

The order in which Java reflection returns the list of fields/properties is not guaranteed.  This is why JAXB implementations do not use it to determine element order.

By default JAXB provides [no guaranteed ordering](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessorOrder.html#value%28%29).  However most (if not all JAXB implementations) use alphabetical ordering since it is deterministic.  To guarantee this ordering you must annotate your class as follows:

```
@XmlAccessorOrder(XmlAccessOrder.ALPHABETICAL)
public class Foo {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Should this also work with inherited properties from your superclass?

Comment: I did this and got reverse alpha ordering when running the marshalling in one environment and normal alpha ordering when running the marshalling in another environment. Any thoughts/suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

```
@XmlType(propOrder={"company", "scheme", "agreementNumber"})
```

It's correct, but have you tried this?

```
@XmlType(propOrder={"Company", "Scheme", "AgreementNumber"})
```

Answer (score 3):

This thread is old but worth throwing how I got my properties to generate xml in the proper order and NOT using alphabetical ordering as that was undesired.  One thing to note is that I am using wink and jaxb which may behave differently then other providers.  Wink was very specific about what was in the propertly list. Even elements I mark as xml transient, or not decorated at all were required to be part of

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Product")
@XmlType(name="",propOrder={"productName","productVersion",..."propN"})
```

...admittedly I don't enough of WHY it works!:)

Comment: The name attribute in the XmlType annotation is not needed, just the propOrder attribute is enough, i.e. @XmlType(propOrder={"productName","productVersion",..."propN"})

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-eleord.html), the order of sibling XML elements is not guaranteed.

Comment: Link no longer works

Answer (score 1):

In `@XmlType(propOrder={"prop1", "prop2"})` you can declare only `propertyName` you declared in the class. You cannot declare

```
XMLElement name (
@XmlElement(name="Company"))
```

in the `XmlType` `propOrder` as mentioned by above..

Answer (score 1):

Just add :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder={"field1", "field2", ...})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is correct :  Please uncomment below line

```
@XmlType(propOrder={"company", "scheme", "agreementNumber"})
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to add the `propOrder` and the `XmlAccessType` annotations to the class.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

@XmlType(propOrder = {"PartyType","PartyName","PartyAddress"})
```