# AccessOrder for Properties in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

In my class, I have more than 80 attributes.

I have to do it into xml file using JAXB using the same order in class.

so please suggest me a propOrder that create automatically or some other way to give in same order as i given in class.

Note:By default i m getting output in alphabetical order

example:

```
Java object : order[id = 1, item = 121, qty = 10, city = QWE, ..........., addr = ASD]

excepted result : In xml file
    <order>
      <id>1</id>
      <item no>121</item no>
      <qty>10</qty>
      .
      .
      .
      .
      <addr>ASD</addr>
    </order>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order that you specify the fields and properties in your class is not significant.  This means that when the JAXB (JSR-222) implementation introspects the class it may not see the fields/properties in the same order that you specified them in.   Alphabetical order is the easiest way to offer consistent ordering.  If you want to specify an order you need to use `propOrder` on `@XmlType`.

Answer (score 4):

If you are creating the xml from the Java object then use

```
@XmlType (propOrder={"id","item",..."addr"})
```

A similar post talks about is and in more details.
[JAXB and property ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435138/jaxb-and-property-ordering)

**For additional check**

If you are converting xml to Java object you should use **sequence** element if you are validating via xsd.

http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_sequence.asp

Comment: Thanks for reply.I need it to generate automatically not manually

Comment: @Ok got it you mean to dynamically set propOrder based on xml