# JAXB order respected by .Net framework service references class generator

Tags: datacontractserializer

According to

[JAXB and property ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435138/jaxb-and-property-ordering)

JAXB can define propOrder. Does the .Net framework service references class generator will respect this order? How to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this goal element in xsd must by defined by sequence:

[Does XML care about the order of elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328867/does-xml-care-about-the-order-of-elements)